# Checking if mobile browser is acessing site

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to check what browser (basically if mobile or not) is accessing my application (ASP.net in VB) as I would like to send them to a different master layout page? Any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the different options suggested in the [How can i detect if the request is coming from a mobile browser in my asp.net MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034697/how-can-i-detect-if-the-request-is-coming-from-a-mobile-browser-in-my-asp-net-mv) thread.

There is a built-in [Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.ismobiledevice.aspx) property available.

Comment: Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice return always false for me, tested with ipad Air  and Huawi P9. It's better to explore Request.UserAgent and chek if is mobile from OS version

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [following article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx) in which Scott Hanselman presents a nice NuGet ([MobileViewEngines](http://nuget.org/packages/MobileViewEngines)) that allows you to achieve this. The NuGet is spec compatible with ASP.NET MVC 4 which supports this functionality out of the box, so all you have to do when you upgrade to ASP.NET MVC 4 is to remove this package.